# Как можно ускорить данный код

Tags: python

Данный код дешифрует шифр путем подбора ключа и сравнивая с словарем на 500.000 слов. ключ может быть 9 значным а для того чтобы дойти хотя бы до 8 значных надо целый час что достаточно долго.
Как можно ускорить ?

```
import string
import numpy as np
import nuitka
from numba import njit, prange
import time

string.digits + string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
alph = string.ascii_uppercase


# print(encrypt('ANCIENT', '420'))  #шифрование
# print(decrypt('NHUDMOVUHB', '13'))  #расшифровывание
def algo(text, k, op):
    k *= len(text) // len(k) + 1
    return ''.join(alph[alph.index(j) + int(k[i]) * op] for i, j in enumerate(text))


def decrypt(message, key):
    return algo(message, key, -1)


def encrypt(message, key):
    return algo(message, key, 1)


word_toDecode = 'Epqv'.upper()
f = open('words.txt')
dictionary = f.readlines()

dictionary = set(word.strip().lower() for word in dictionary)

duplicate_words = []


def brute():
    for x in prange(10000000):
        s = decrypt(word_toDecode, str(x))
        if s.lower() in dictionary:
            for i in duplicate_words:
                if i == s.lower(): break
            else:
                duplicate_words.append(s.lower())
                print(s + ' Key - ' + str(x))



def start():
    cur_time = time.time()
    brute()
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - cur_time)
    f.close()


start()
```

Comment: Попробуй cython использовать.

Comment: alph.index() ищет символ в алфавите сканированием строки, используйте обратный словарь вида { смещение: сивол } для быстрого поиска. А еще лучше посмотрите что там у вас за буквы в каком порядке и сделайте формулу для прямого пересчета смещения в ascii код символа